# on Ec2 when in try to download application packages using yum install httpd i get an error

Tags: installation, yum

Error downloading packages:

```
  apr-util-1.6.1-5.amzn2.0.2.x86_64:  No more mirrors to try.
  generic-logos-httpd-18.0.0-4.amzn2.noarch: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
  httpd-2.4.53-1.amzn2.x86_64:  No more mirrors to try.
  httpd-filesystem-2.4.53-1.amzn2.noarch: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
  httpd-tools-2.4.53-1.amzn2.x86_64: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
  apr-util-bdb-1.6.1-5.amzn2.0.2.x86_64: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
  mod_http2-1.15.19-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
  mailcap-2.1.41-2.amzn2.noarch: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
  apr-1.7.0-9.amzn2.x86_64: Errno 256 No more mirrors to try.
```

Comment: What is the command you run to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change your security group.

- In inbound rules make it: `HTTPS, HTTP, All ICMP - IPv4 and ssh`
- In outbound rules make it: `all traffic`